# Azure VPN Client "Status = VPN Platform did not trigger connection"

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

Several users have been randomly experiencing this issue when trying to connect using Azure VPN Client for about a week now. Some have had the issue for a week straight, others have had it for a period of time before it resolved itself.

When trying to connect, the authentication succeeds but the VPN fails to connect with the error "Status = VPN Platform did not trigger connection". The only similar issue I found when searching relates to the VPN client not having permission to run-in the background, but this seems to be a different issue.

Things we've tried so far:

- Resetting and doubly reseting the gateway
- Rebooting the machine
- Reinstalling the VPN profile on the client
- Regenerating the VPN profile
- Reinstalling the VPN client on the machine
- Toggling various network & app settings

The logs in the Azure portal show the user successfully authenticating, but nothing to show the VPN failing to connect. All the affected machines are running versions of Windows 10 and are up to date. The problem seems to be specific to the machine itself - using a different set of credentials or a different network makes no difference. The problem is occurring in multiple locations and other machines at the same location are unaffected. The only pattern seems to be that older machines are more likely to be affected but I'm not even totally sure that's anything other than coincidence. Five or so machines have experienced the issue and three are currently affect out of fifteen or so total.

Best guess at this point is that an update caused the issue. Any further troubleshooting suggestions are welcome at this point as I'm unsure of the cause and unable to reproduce the problem. Azure support say the gateway configuration looks fine but are unsure what's causing the problem - they've just had me run packet capture on both ends and I'm waiting to see what they say about the results but it's causing quite an issue for users without VPN access.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue  "Status = VPN Platform did not trigger connection" and tried all the same steps as above.  After getting no where with the basics, I opened a ticket MS and they suggested that I restart the rasman (Remote Access Connection Manager) service.  After the service restart the Azure VPN client connected without issue.  I also set the startup type to Automatic (delayed). BTW an admin has to make this change.

Comment: Thanks @user3120640 ! I had the same issue and the restart helped.
It didn't do anything on restart but I had to click on `Go to details`  end the task, and start it again in services.

Comment: Wow. Thanks much, that did the trick for me as well.
Had to kill the process in the process :)
Instructions for how to kill the service:
https://tecadmin.net/force-stop-a-service-windows/

Answer (score 1):

Please check in if Background Apps in settings is turned on. It should be turned on. Let Azure VPN remain active and turn off the rest of the apps which you dont use it frequently.

Comment: As noted, this was a different issue. Restarting RAS as suggested by the accepted answer did fix it though.

Comment: This worked for me. Also is what Microsoft suggest in docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-vpn-point-to-site-connection-problems#vpn-client-error-dialing-vpn-connection-vpn-connection-name-status--vpn-platform-did-not-trigger-connection